# getting an error: unexpected token ILLEGAL in mongodb

Tags: bash, shell

I am getting an error: `Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` when i am trying to execute the following command:

```
mkdir \data\rs1 \data\rs2 \data\rs3
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: How does this question relate to mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the wrong directory delimiter.

use `/` instead of `\`

```
mkdir /data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the proper command,

```
mkdir -p /data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3
```